# Create static library in Xcode 4

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, xcode4, static-libraries

I can't figure out how to create a cocoa touch static library in Xcode 4.

I've created static library in Xcode 3 and it worked fine. I used [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fFn2o0aEbRQ). Thanks for the help.

First step I create cocoa touch static library

[image]

Next we can see our static library in product directory. But now this uncompiled library.

[image]

Next step I add some objective-c class. This class is will perform various actions, for example show NSLog messages.

[image]

Then I made sure there is this class exist in compile source

[image]

After that I build my target

[image]

Now I use this static library in other projects, but when I use it I get a error when linking files with my static library.

Comment: You didn't specify the problem you are facing!

Comment: create a static library in the XCode3 and XCode4 are different - this is my problem

Comment: Different, but how different?

Comment: when i use xcode 3 for creating static library i follow next step:
- first i add new target and choice 'cocoa touch' -> 'static library'
- next after adding library i drag into compiling sources my class .m
- next i build my static library

Comment: but I do not know how to repeat these steps in the XСode 4

Answer (score 1):

Open Xcode > Create New Project > iOS > Framework & Library > Cocoa Touch Static Library

Comment: I did as you wrote. Then I created a few classes and do build my library. After that I drag my build library and header classes into my other project. When I import header and call some method in my static library and after run i get error: ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/dev01/Desktop/libLiba.a, missing required architecture i386 in file
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyClass", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in new2AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: What is /Users/dev01/Desktop/libLiba.a?

Comment: I changed my post. Now I have described my steps to create a static library.

Comment: Do you get that error when you compile the project for the simulator or for an actual device? The fact that it says architecture i386 is missing sounds like your compiling your new project for the simulator, but the static library is compiled for the device.

Comment: Yes, I realized the error, it really is that as you write. i build my static lib for iOS Device and Run it on simulator. You know how to make a library for simulator and device?

Comment: I don't think you can. It's either one or the other. You can however, make your static library a sub-project of your app in Xcode and compile them both at once.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this myself and, on [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520977/build-fat-static-library-device-simulator-using-xcode-and-sdk-4), found this:

[iOS-Universal-Framework](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework)

Answer (score 0):

To create an static library you can try to figure out with example example here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial