# Creating Static Library from xcode-4

Tags: ios, xcode4

I created the Cocoa touch Static library and wants to create the one Static library for iOS deveice and simulator both.

So i am using this link for creating lib.

http://red-glasses.com/index.php/tutorials/xcode4-make-a-library-in-one-file-that-works-on-both-device-and-simulator/

in this blog 
Finding of lib-
Read the output from the Build (you may have to select “All messages” in Xcode 4, or it will just say “success!”) – the last line tells you exactly where to find your library.

But i am new to xcode4 so 
Please suggest How i check the library is created or not and where i find that library if created.

Answer (score 0):

[image: look at the output and right click here]

Right click on the runcustom shell script line.
Select Copy Transcript For Shown Results
Paste in into a text editor.
At the bottom is the path to the output.
:)

also look here if you haven't
[another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520977/build-fat-static-library-device-simulator-using-xcode-and-sdk-4)