# How to get MGSplitViewController working in Monotouch?

Tags: iphone, xcode, binding, xamarin.ios, simulator

I downloaded the MGSplitViewController project here:
https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController

and the bindings here:
https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/MGSplitViewController

Where do I get the "a" file from? If I build the project in Xcode I get an "app" file, a demo of the controller.

Also: what target do I have to build the "a" file for? A separate one for Simulator and one for iPhone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: The project linked below has been deleted. You can easily create your own nested view controllers these days by using view controller containment.

Alright, I'll add an another answer myself, although I consider Poupos's answer a valid one but I found a solution that fits my needs even better: I converted MGSplitViewController to Monotouch. :-)
It is available as MTSplitViewController on GitHub at https://github.com/Krumelur/MTSplitViewController

I really hope it helps others, too.

Comment: Is there a current link or project for this?

Comment: It's discontinued because it is no longer required now that it is easy to nest view controllers

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like the source code in GIT provides the Xcode project file to create a library, only an application: that includes the sample and the control.

You'll need to build (part of) the source (stuff under /MGSplitViewController/) as a static library first (new project). If you use a FAT library then you can include both i386, armv6 and armv7 binaries - which will make it easier to use afterward with your MonoTouch project.

Comment: Okay, did that. I have an "a" file. I added it to my project. I also have a DLL from the make file of the bindings. How/where do I add that ?

Comment: Add a reference to your project from the binding assembly you generated. Next add the **additional mtouch arguments** (Project Options, iPhone Build) to link the native library. See http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/linking_native_libraries for details.

Comment: Okay, almost there. It builds but does not launch the app.How can I create a FAT library? I'm so lost in Xcode4!

Comment: Look at **lipo** for a command-line tool to create FAT libraries (e.g. `man lipo`) or for Xcode see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520977/build-fat-static-library-device-simulator-using-xcode-and-sdk-4/3647187#3647187