# How to compile libmms to a fat static library for iPhone device and simulator(armv6,armv7 and i386)

Tags: iphone, ios, static-libraries, libmms

How to compile libmms to a fat static library for iPhone device and simulator(armv6,armv7 and i386)?

The source code is at http://sourceforge.net/projects/libmms/, please give me some guide, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This post on SO is probably the best answer for your issue. I'm assuming you are using Xcode 4 which no longer builds libraries into universal static libraries.

[Build fat static library for simulator and device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520977/build-fat-static-library-device-simulator-using-xcode-and-sdk-4)