# How to change ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT to i386?

Tags: iphone, cpu-architecture

Building application for iOS Device so need to change the architecture from armv7,armv6  to i386.

How to change it?

or

How to build the application for i386 architecture?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the architecture in the Build Settings under Architectures (you may also need to modify Valid Architectures too?). Just to note, if you are building for the iOS Device then you need to build for armv6 and armv7 and not i386. You can set different architecture types for each target and also for the project as a whole (under Project).

[image: Architecture]

Comment: what i need to type in that! directly i368 or ?

Comment: If you are compiling for the iOS Device then you need to compile for armv6 and armv7 NOT i386. You shouldn't have to change this setting anyway if you just want to build (to distribute or submit), the default Xcode sets up is just fine

Comment: okay! when i am importing into new project i do getting this warning!  libSignatureLibrary.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)

Comment: If you are building a Static Library for use in other projects then you need to build a 'fat' library which includes both armv6/armv7 and i386. I had to do this previously and used the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3647187/846698