# ios: how to build static library for simulator?

Tags: ios

Hi I am having trouble testing a static library through the simulator. If I build the static library when the scheme is iPhone simulator, no *.a file gets generated. It is only generated if the scheme is iOS device. How to do this?

Comment: A [little search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520977/build-fat-static-library-device-simulator-using-xcode-and-sdk-4) goes a long way.

Comment: what makes you think I havent searched?

Comment: Because googling your exact question results in a lot of information on building a fat static library, and your question provides no suggestion that you have tried anything listed there. If I was erroneous in my assumption, I do apologize.