# How should I pack an iOS library?

Tags: ios, frameworks, static-libraries

We supply an iOS framework that serves as an extension related to taking pictures.
How do you suggest we package this library for easy integration?

Thanks,
Uri.

Comment: How long is a piece of string? Is lobster better than anchovies? In other words, this question doesn't have any sort of definite answer. It depends on your circumstance, users, use cases, etc.

Comment: In a box with a user manual and 5.25" floppies. ;-)

Comment: In all seriousness, I think [this is the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5721978/77939). I'll mark this question as a duplicate.