# Custom skins for iOS library

Tags: iphone, ios, skinning

**Background**

I need to deliver library which will be used in other projets. It's front end to server API - contains API client and a few views to input data, make choices, commit changes - usual UI with very generic look & feel. Developer calls "start" it launches view, guides user throught some screens and then launches delegate definied by said developer.

EDIT: To clarify, I've that library up and running, my main concern is what is the best approach when it comes to applying skin from outside of the library.

**What I want to achieve**

- To allow customisation of views by developers using my library
- Server API logic should not be altered by developers(so compiled library)
- Skinning should be as simple as possible

**TL/DR**

Is it possible to create compiled iOS library that contains views which can be skinned by typical iOS dev without 1000 page manual :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can distribute it as universal static library or .framework. Currnently both options require custom build scripts, but there are samples like [Build fat static library (device + simulator) using Xcode and SDK 4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520977/build-fat-static-library-device-simulator-using-xcode-and-sdk-4) . However how you make skinning without 1000 page manual is up to you ;)

Comment: That part is already done :) However, now skin is fixed and sometimes looks very different than target application. So what's most interesting for me is what would be most dev-friendly solution to apply skin from outside of the lib. Anyway thanks, your answer has some useful tips :)