# Does a static library add inside another static library? iOS/Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm creatic a static library to distribute to other projects (they don't see the library source code), and I wonder some questions:

-I follow this guide:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Articles/creating.html
I create a .a file, several .h files and another .bundle file. The question is that my project library uses includes ResstKit (and uses it). In the product directory I see my library .a and the RestKit .a file. Do I have to distribute that restkit .a file? or is it already included inside my own .a file?

-The Apple guide doesn't say anything about fat or universal libraries. How can I create my library for the device and simulator at the same time? I see some scripts on the net, but I guess there must be some option there. What do you think? (BTW, do fat and universal have the same meaning?)

-Is there anyway to tell the target zip everything or create a DMG package? I guess using a Python script is possible, but I mean using any Xcode option.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can find out using the nm command. This will list the contents of a static library.

Comment: [Build fat static library (device + simulator) using Xcode and SDK 4+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520977/build-fat-static-library-device-simulator-using-xcode-and-sdk-4)