# If some library is compiled in arm, is that mean I cannot use it in the simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, arm

I am referencing some library(lib***.a) which seems to be built for ARM? Does that mean I cannot build/run the whole application in the simulator(i386) environment?

Comment: You're building an already built library? Please clarify.

Comment: add more to the question.

Comment: you cannot run arm code on an x86 simulator and expect it to work, no.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct, unless it is a ["fat" static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520977/build-fat-static-library-device-simulator-using-xcode-and-sdk-4), which includes the build for both the simulator and the device in the same library.

Alternatively, there may be a separate library file (usually with the same name) that you can substitute that is built for the simulator.