# iOS Universal Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries

Hi I'm trying to make my first framework in iOS. I've been searching for a few days and finally got it, i'm using this [Tutorial](https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework#first_parties) which is very simple and straightforward.

But I'm having a bit of a problem understanding one thing. My app that is using the framework can build and run with a **real device** but can't do it with the **simulator**.

The Aggregate Target script puts together the two static libraries (Simulator and Device) in one Binary:

```
xcrun lipo -create "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${SF_EXECUTABLE_PATH}" "${SF_OTHER_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${SF_EXECUTABLE_PATH}" -output "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${SF_WRAPPER_NAME}/Versions/A/${SF_TARGET_NAME}"
```

I build that Aggregator Target and go to my **Products** folder and has two folders in it:[image]

I'm using the framework that's inside **Debug-iphoneos**.
Shouldn't be only one folder, since I compile to one Universal Framework?
What am I missing or doing wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I created universal static lib by adding script. More http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520977/build-fat-static-library-device-simulator-using-xcode-and-sdk-4

Comment: I've tried that script but gives me an error, Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

Comment: take a look at accepted answer, actually, there are lot of correct answers to choose

Comment: As an alternative solution check this repo: https://github.com/gurhub/universal-framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this to build Dropbox universal framework.  Make product and version info changes to suite yours.

```
# Sets the target folders and the final framework product.
FMK_NAME=DropboxSDK
FMK_VERSION=5.5

# Install dir will be the final output to the framework.
# The following line create it in the root folder of the current project.
INSTALL_DIR=${SRCROOT}/Products/${FMK_NAME}.framework

# Working dir will be deleted after the framework creation.
WRK_DIR=build
DEVICE_DIR=${WRK_DIR}/Release-iphoneos/${FMK_NAME}.framework
SIMULATOR_DIR=${WRK_DIR}/Release-iphonesimulator/${FMK_NAME}.framework

# Building both architectures.
xcodebuild -configuration "Release" -target "${FMK_NAME}" -sdk iphoneos
xcodebuild -configuration "Release" -target "${FMK_NAME}" -sdk iphonesimulator

# Cleaning the oldest.
if [ -d "${INSTALL_DIR}" ]
then
rm -rf "${INSTALL_DIR}"
fi

# Creates and renews the final product folder.
mkdir -p "${INSTALL_DIR}"
mkdir -p "${INSTALL_DIR}/Versions"
mkdir -p "${INSTALL_DIR}/Versions/${FMK_VERSION}"
mkdir -p "${INSTALL_DIR}/Versions/${FMK_VERSION}/Resources"
mkdir -p "${INSTALL_DIR}/Versions/${FMK_VERSION}/Headers"

# Creates the internal links.
# It MUST uses relative path, otherwise will not work when the folder is copied/moved.
ln -s "${FMK_VERSION}" "${INSTALL_DIR}/Versions/Current"
ln -s "Versions/Current/Headers" "${INSTALL_DIR}/Headers"
ln -s "Versions/Current/Resources" "${INSTALL_DIR}/Resources"
ln -s "Versions/Current/${FMK_NAME}" "${INSTALL_DIR}/${FMK_NAME}"

# Copies the headers and resources files to the final product folder.
cp -R "${DEVICE_DIR}/Headers/" "${INSTALL_DIR}/Versions/${FMK_VERSION}/Headers/"
cp -R "${DEVICE_DIR}/" "${INSTALL_DIR}/Versions/${FMK_VERSION}/Resources/"

# Removes the binary and header from the resources folder.
rm -r "${INSTALL_DIR}/Versions/${FMK_VERSION}/Resources/Headers" "${INSTALL_DIR}/Versions/${FMK_VERSION}/Resources/${FMK_NAME}"

# Uses the Lipo Tool to merge both binary files (i386 + armv6/armv7) into one Universal final product.
lipo -create "${DEVICE_DIR}/${FMK_NAME}" "${SIMULATOR_DIR}/${FMK_NAME}" -output "${INSTALL_DIR}/Versions/${FMK_VERSION}/${FMK_NAME}"

rm -r "${WRK_DIR}"
```

Comment: what to pass if my framework name is abc.framework then ? what i have to change in above script