# Crash when using lib file in proj

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I have followed this tutorial [LINK](http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/04/07/creating-static-libraries-for-ios/)

but i get a linker error when i added the lib and its .h to the project.

i searched google and i found that -ObjC and -all_load should be addd in setting i did it but the error couldn't be solved.The error is as follows:

> ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/techvedika/Desktop/RND/MathTest/MathTest/iCodeBlogsMathLibrary/libICodeMathUtils.a, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/techvedika/Desktop/RND/MathTest/MathTest/iCodeBlogsMathLibrary/libICodeMathUtils.a (3 slices)
>   Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MathFunctions", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

how do i solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please check `lipo -info libICodeMathUtils.a` on terminal. If it is not listing architecture i386 that means your library is not build for simulator. And it will not work on simulator

Comment: Architectures in the fat file: /Users/techvedika/Desktop/iCodeBlogsMathLibrary/libICodeMathUtils.a are: armv7 (cputype (12) cpusubtype (11)) (cputype (16777228) cpusubtype (0))  what should i do in order for it to wrk in simulator.

Comment: Do you have source of that library?

Comment: follow [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial) to create static library. You need to build the library against simulator and device. And combine both to create a universal library to work on both simulator and device

Comment: I have tried tutorial i could not build the lib project with simulator settings.Also, I could not find the tool "LIPO" which was mentioned in the tutorial.Can u please help me with this.

Comment: `lipo` you can try it from the terminal. `lipo -create <simulator_lib>.a <device_lib>.a -output lib.a`

Comment: how do i create <simulator_lib>.a.Can u give me an example?

Comment: While building select the simulator instead of device. This will build for simulator. Don't forget to build in release  mode

Comment: did as u said but the build succeeded but the lib file was not generated :( where do i find them.

Comment: Are you able to build it for device?

Comment: i got it now. first  build it for device and then for simulator then the build was generated.then using the LIPO cmd i generated final build which works for both device and simulator.Thanks a lot Anil.

Answer (score 1):

obviously, this is not a crash , it's just a link error, your project lack of **i386 version libICodeMathUtils.a**, so you should first add libICodeMathUtils.a to your project.

Comment: how do i get i386 versiosn library are there any settings?

Comment: @user2798258,follow this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520977/build-fat-static-library-device-simulator-using-xcode-and-sdk-4), you can get a universal library include device and simulator.

Answer (score 0):

The MathFunctions class is missing. Either from your application project or from the SimpleLibrary.a that you use. Make sure it is part of the compilation and linking steps of your build.