# Does lipo increase final binary size?

Tags: xcode, build, executable, archive, lipo

I know I can use `lipo` to create a universal static library that I can then include in my project.

It's convenient because it builds for the simulator or device, but will it make my project's archive bigger than if I had (a) included the static library built for device only or (b) made the static library project a subproject of my project?

Comment: Isn't it easier to just try it to see? I _think_ that as long as your executable is not a universal binary, it will only include the pieces it needs from your static library.

Comment: If [Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com) tried to do everything himself and never asked for help, then this site probably wouldn't exist. Do not underestimate the [Power of the Master Mind](http://www.sacred-texts.com/nth/tgr/tgr15.htm). The answer to this question will help those with the same question in the future.