# add framework to static library xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

i am trying to add this mpos.framework to my Static library but i get this :

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPMpos", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libSerenity.a(Widget.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[image]

i should add the mpos.framework to the DependentApp also?

Answer (score 0):

`i should add the mpos.framework to the DependentApp also?`  - You can easily answer this by trying it.

My guess is that this is not your problem. It looks like mpos.framework (and its internal library) is not FAT library and is compiled for ARM architecture(s) only. It probably do not contain i386 (simulator) version of the compiled code. You can find more information about FAT libraries here: [Build fat static library (device + simulator) using Xcode and SDK 4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520977/build-fat-static-library-device-simulator-using-xcode-and-sdk-4)