# ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, dylib, xctest

I'm having a issue compiling my app for Simulator. In the device runs perfectly but once I tried it to compile in simulator I get the following error:

```
ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib built for MacOSX file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest' for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I checked before posting this question, but the answers I found in stackoverflow, like to run this,

```
export PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xct‌oolchain/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:$PATH
```

or

The problem was that Xcode 5 replaces gcc with clang and adds in a "-triple" option that    specifies OSX as the target. If you pass "-miphoneos-version-min=7.0" on both gcc command lines it works. You can see the clang command line if you pass "--verbose" to gcc. It's also necessary to add to the PATH for Xcode 5 so that cmake can find the necessary tools: export PATH=/Applications/Xcode5-DP6.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xct‌​oolchain/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode5-DP6.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:$PATH None of this is official.. but works for me so far.

I dont really understand how to to do this. Any help, please?

Comment: I guess your problem is fat static library problem. You need to compile your static library for both device and simulator. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520977/build-fat-static-library-device-simulator-using-xcode-and-sdk-4 this link might help. Also you need to search for static fat library.

Comment: Thanks Güngör, but there is not an easier way without having to create and compile in command tool makefiles?

Comment: I had the same problem on iOS6 with different library. It know it is hard to do. Unfortunately, that is the only way I know

Answer (score 10):

Check `Build Settings` for your test target. This values should look similar:

[image]

If you have any escaped symbol, consider to fix it. I had here : `\"`. I just removed them

Also notice: order is important!

**P.S. from GraehamF** It's always a good thing to `Build -> Clean` and restart Xcode, so the changes to take affect

Comment: Ok, now my error changed to this-> ld: warning: ignoring file p\342D\323\375, missing required architecture i386 in file p\342D\323\375 (3 slices)

Comment: Ok, the error that I had before came back. Should I add any framework search path to my main target!? the same as my test target?

Comment: You don't need any framework search paths in your main target except you explicitly use framework that require that.

Comment: Missing architecture - means you don't build your dependency with required architecture or you don't have it in static library that you use

Comment: Try to set `Build active architecture only` to NO for dependency target, it will force build for every architecture that you suppoty

Comment: I tried build active architecture to NO, but still the same. I took off the XCTest, and seems that the problem is somewhere else. Here is the error I'm getting now ->  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CAShapeLayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AMTagView.o
  "_kCAFillRuleEvenOdd", referenced from:
      -[AMTagView drawRect:] in AMTagView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: `CAShapeLayer` is referenced in `QuartzCore.framework`. Add link to Quartz in your test target too.

Comment: Thanks. Finally I solved by hiding the instances that were using _kCAFillRuleEvenOdd.

Comment: had similar issue, had to clean and restart XCode for the changes to take effect and the project to build though :/

Answer (score 2):

When I faced this error with an XCode project, I open the file `???.xcodeproj` *(in a SubLime Text editor)* and removed the below lines. The warning will no longer be there!

```
LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = (
    "\"${PROJECT_DIR}/../../../../../usr/lib\"/**",
    "\"${PROJECT_DIR}/../../../../../usr/lib\"/**",
);
```