# Cannot build on IOS Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm developing an iOS app with framework integration until yesterday I could run my App on an Simulator, but since then I get the Error "Building for iOS Simulator, but the linked library 'myLibrary.a' was built for iOS."

Did anything change with the new update?
Can I find a workaround for this problem or do I need to run my app only on an actual Device from now on?

Comment: Is 'myLibrary.a' something you control?

Comment: is your question answered here: - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092201/ld-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-against-dylib ?

Comment: Phillip Mills No its not.

Answer (score 0):

On [this therad from forums.developer.apple](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/130684) edford mentioned:

> Having **x86_64** code is not sufficient to distinguish if a binary is
>   intended for the **iOS Simulator**, a **macOS** app, or a **Mac
>   Catalyst** app. Combing built binaries across different destinations
>   (which includes the simulator vs. device binaries) is not a supported
>   combination -- **there is no Apple platform where ARM code and x86_64
>   code in the same binary is a correct configuration.**
>
> If this is your library, you should have your app [build it from
>   source as a dependency of your Xcode project](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/devcc9f6bfb2), so that the right
>   platform information is included based on the build target.
>
> If this is your library but you have a specific reason for it to be
>   pre-compiled, please [build it as an XCFramework](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev544efab96). XCFrameworks
>   correctly separate out binaries that have the right architectures for
>   the different platforms you target. In addition to instructions on how
>   to build such a XCFramework linked earlier, we have a [WWDC talk
>   illustrating it](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/416/).
>
> If this library is from a framework vendor (either as source or a
>   pre-compiled binary), or you integrate a vendor's library into your
>   app with a third party dependency manager, please consult with the
>   library vendor or dependency manager for support.