# How to make simulator to be supported by a specific SDK?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I am currently using [Vuforia SDK](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/sdk/ios), and I am testing it on a real **iOS Device**, since the documentation of it doesn't support **iOS Simulator**. It has a `.a` library that I need to import it to the `Frameworks`

My question is this, is there any way how to make changes in a specific library (framework) to support **iOS simulators**? Any hints or suggestions are welcome!

*P.S I am not referring to Vuforia SDK, I just want to know it in General Occassions*

Comment: Sure, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520977/build-fat-static-library-device-simulator-using-xcode-and-sdk-4

Comment: I searched a lot and I saw that post before, but it tells how to create a library and add Build Settings to it, not how to modify it or do any trick to make the ones who don't support simulators, support them.

Comment: There's no magic and tricks, you are giving instructions to a machine. To make a fat library you need either source code to compile both architectures or two linked libraries for different architectures that you can "merge" into one fat library.

Comment: I don't mean this, but if I have a specific .a library is there any way to decompile or reconfigure it