# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) issues in my app

Tags: ios, linker, static-libraries

I have created a static library to perform some mathematical operations `libICodeMathUtils.a` and add this static library with a .h file `MathFunctions.h` . But when I run my project then I am having this issue. You can see in this screen shot.

[image]

Comment: The static library is not compiled for i386 architecture and that is what you are possibly using in your project's build configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I think your static library file is not compatible with simulator because simulator supports i386 so you have to create universal library (static fat library) check this  [Build fat static library (device + simulator) using Xcode and SDK 4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520977/build-fat-static-library-device-simulator-using-xcode-and-sdk-4)