# How to make sure whether my static library works fine

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin, static-libraries, sup

We are developing a Xamarin iOS application by making use of SUP MBOs. We have generated the code in Objective C and in order to access it from C# code base(Xamarin), this generated code should be bundled as a static library (.a file) with some SUP specific static libraries and SUP header classes. We are able to create universal static library file(.a file) with help of  [Build fat static library (device + simulator) using Xcode and SDK 4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520977/build-fat-static-library-device-simulator-using-xcode-and-sdk-4)

Now my question is how to make sure whether the universal static library file which we have created is working or not?

We have created a sample static library file by just implementing a add method and were able to access it through C# code(using Xamarin) but we are getting this error -## MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: _OBJC_CLASS ## when using SUP generated code. we are  giving all correct values to all properties in build setting of Xcode  "other linker flags", "library search path", "header search path" but I have no idea how we can go ahead with this. We are not sure whether we are missing something or in wrong path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option is to [create a Binding project](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/binding_objc_libs/) for the native library (and a corresponding test application that exercises the binding project to make sure it works).

If you have any problems (build/linker/runtime errors), we'll need to see the header file, the binding code you've created and the full build output in order to diagnose the problem properly.