# Cocoa Touch Framework architecture issue / production build

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, frameworks

I built an iOS Framework.
After I added the framework to my project and run on my device, it worked fine. But when I try to run it on the Simulator, I got some error.

```
ld: warning: ignoring file MyFramework.framework/Framework, missing required architecture x86_64 in file MyFramework.framework/MyFramework (2 slices)
```

Also got this one:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
```

With a list of strings/methods and such that were referenced from.

How could I fix that?

Also,  I want my `Framework` to run on all devices/simulators since iOS7+ (Production), I've read this post **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039470/xcode-6-ios-creating-a-cocoa-touch-framework-architectures-issues)** that tells me to use `lipo`, but I understand that I have to create an `Aggregate` target. I just don't have this in my `Other` section of XCode 6.2.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after 2 days of search, a lot of reading on the web and mostly at StackOverflow.com I found this question:

[Xcode - symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 (iOS Lib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24346637/xcode-symbols-not-found-for-architecture-x86-64-ios-lib)

Select your **Target** and in `Build Setting` it should look like that:

[image: target]

Now, select the **Aggregate Target**, click on the `Build Settings` and should look like that:

[image: aggregate target]

If you want to better understand how to create a framework, read this question and the answer of this question, there is a lot of information there, this is what helped me:

[Running 1 of 1 custom shell scripts freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29165442/running-1-of-1-custom-shell-scripts-freeze/29174838#29174838)

Enjoy and good luck!