# My macOS project build failed after upgrade to Xcode9

Tags: build, compilation, xcode9

here is the error description:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_verify", referenced
>   from:
>         _HIDGetDeviceInfo in HIDUtilities.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

It happened after upgrade Xcode to version 9.1
HIDUtilities.o is not third-party SDK, HIDUtilities.h and HIDUtilities.c are files in my project.

Any suggestion is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode - symbol(s) not found for architecture x86\_64 (iOS Lib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24346637/xcode-symbols-not-found-for-architecture-x86-64-ios-lib)

Comment: nope, it's different with that, thanks all the same.