# Can a cocoa touch static library contain another static library?

Tags: ios

I want to create a static library which contain another static library, how to do?

Comment: Do you mean you want to merge two static libraries into one?

Comment: I mean, I used lib1.a static library in my project , and then I want my whole project packaged into a static library lib2.a, can I?

Comment: You can put all the code of your application into a static library, but not all of the rest of the application (resources etc.). As @Vitaly mentioned, you can create a framework. Perhaps it would be best if you described in more detail what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean embedding dependent library then answer is NO. You can read a little more http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/code/ios/Radar_15800975_iOS_Frameworks.20140112.html or so. I'd recommend to make a Framework instead of static library.

If you just want to make "fat" library which contains different versions of same library for different platforms then answer is YES ([Build fat static library (device + simulator) using Xcode and SDK 4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520977/build-fat-static-library-device-simulator-using-xcode-and-sdk-4)).