# Xcode 6 combined framework simulator/device binary

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Over the years, there have been questions about a combined binary for simulator and device builds for static libraries ([Build fat static library (device + simulator) using Xcode and SDK 4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520977/build-fat-static-library-device-simulator-using-xcode-and-sdk-4)).

There have been some solutions (https://gist.github.com/adamgit/3705459) overall but I cannot find any solution that works for Xcode 6 and the cocoa touch framework. Any run script that I ended up utilizing (https://kodmunki.wordpress.com/2014/11/07/universal-cocoa-touch-frameworks-for-ios-8/) crashed the system for me with infinite run loops of some sort.

Is there a run script for building Cocoa Touch Frameworks with Xcode 6/iOS 8 such that both simulator and device versions are compiled into the same binary?

Comment: What does your question have to do with Cocoa?

Comment: My bad. Removed the tag 'Cocoa'. The question is related to the cocoa touch frameworks; but not cocoa. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We never had inf. run loops with this process: https://kodmunki.wordpress.com/2014/11/07/universal-cocoa-touch-frameworks-for-ios-8/ ... That said, that process is outdated due to fats failure to pass Apple validation. We have a new process (remix). It works for us, so it's been posted. You're welcome to give it a shot! Happy hacking! :{)}