# Using XCode to build a "assembly.a" ? - Newbie

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin

Super newbie question.

I need to build the ZipArchive (https://github.com/mattconnolly/ZipArchive) into a ZipArchive.a file to use it in another technology (Xamarin))

I have opened the ZipArchive.xcodeproj in Xcode

How do I build it to a .a file?

I've tried running it in XCode and it says all went well, but no .a file appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create static fat library(.a file ) in Xcode you can refer this link 
[Build fat static library (device + simulator) using Xcode and SDK 4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520977/build-fat-static-library-device-simulator-using-xcode-and-sdk-4)

Once you create static library you have to create binding project in xamarin in order to access this .a file .

you can find .a file under products folder in Xcode project navigator just right click on it and choose show in finder .

i have done one project where i am using xamarin with .a if you have any query you can let me know