# Linker Errors After Migrating to XCode Derived Data Build Path

Tags: ios, xcode, static-linking

I have an XCode 4 project that used the `Legacy` build location (`File->Project Settings->Advanced`).

The project has three targets. A static library `A` consumed a static library `B` and then linked into a consuming app `C`.

I utilized the gist from this question ([Build fat static library (device + simulator) using Xcode and SDK 4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520977/build-fat-static-library-device-simulator-using-xcode-and-sdk-4)) to build a universal static library of `A` and `B` and then they're `lipo`'d into one `.a` that is linked in `C`. All works wonderfully.

Recently, I migrated (experimented) with setting the `Build Location` to the XCode default in DerivedData, my application `C` has started to have linker errors related to the objects defined in `A`. It's quite confusing since I've validated that the fat library is being created correctly.

Is there some other caveat to moving to the XCode default that I should be aware of?

**Update**

Updating with images. With `Legacy` selected, everything builds fine. With `Xcode Default`, I get linker errors. This setting isn't even store in your project so I have to make sure all machine building this project use that setting. I don't understand the correlation between this setting and the linker errors. Has anyone else encountered this?

[image]

**Update 2**

I've discovered this has to do with the way I bundle in library `A` into `B`. I use `libtool` in the following manner.

```
 libtool -static -o superlib.a out/*.a
```

This command succeeds but the resulting `.a` doesn't link properly with the application. If I take all the `out/*.a` files and link them independently with the app, it works fine. Also w/ the `Legacy` build location, the `superlib.a` works fine.

Perplexing.