# xcode >= 8 cannot compile my objective-c library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios10, xcodebuild

I'm trying to compile my objective-c library with Xcode (or xcodebuild) but it seems that Xcode is only taking the last two numbers of my "Base SDK" (10.1 in my case) build setting :

```
xcodebuild   -scheme mylib   -workspace mylib_objc.xcworkspace -sdk "iphonesimulator10.1" build
```

output error :

```
    /bin/sh -c /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mylib_objc-dcainaehwbdhdeeyoykilqflodnx/Build/Intermediates/mylib.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/mylib.build/Script-AEDFEE9B1B25C0FD00756827.sh
XCode has selected SDK: iphonesimulator with version: 0.1 (although back-targetting: 7.0)
...therefore, OTHER_SDK_TO_BUILD = iphoneos0.1
RECURSION: I am the root ... recursing all missing build targets NOW...
RECURSION: ...about to invoke: xcodebuild -configuration "Debug" -project "mylib.xcodeproj" -target "mylib" -sdk "iphoneos0.1" build RUN_CLANG_STATIC_ANALYZER=NO BUILD_DIR="/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mylib_objc-dcainaehwbdhdeeyoykilqflodnx/Build/Products" BUILD_ROOT="/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mylib_objc-dcainaehwbdhdeeyoykilqflodnx/Build/Products" SYMROOT="/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mylib_objc-dcainaehwbdhdeeyoykilqflodnx/Build/Products"
xcodebuild: error: SDK "iphoneos0.1" cannot be located.
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 64
```

I then tried with a coworker who has xCode 8 (and therefore base sdk=10.0), the error was `xcodebuild: error: SDK "iphoneos0.0" cannot be located.`

Any idea how to force the compilation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are buiding your library with an old build script. Checkout my answer here

[Build fat static library (device + simulator) using Xcode and SDK 4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520977/build-fat-static-library-device-simulator-using-xcode-and-sdk-4/39573000#39573000)

and update your script then you should be fine.