# Building a multiarch app with Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to get so called fat binary with iOS app. So, I defined in my Xcode:

```
Architectures : Standard (arm64 armv7)
Build Active Architecture Only : No
Valid Architecures: arm64 armv7
```

And build process succeeded. The output file is `app.ipa`. But, I have a problem with compability on 32 bit devices. So, I investigate to `app.ipa`: `lipo -info app.ipa`. Actually, it says that is is non-fat arm64 file.

But why? 
After all, I configured correctly.

When I create empty project and set conifg as above it works.

How to resolve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build fat static library (device + simulator) using Xcode and SDK 4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520977/build-fat-static-library-device-simulator-using-xcode-and-sdk-4)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for creating fat framework/library, then [Adam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3647187/4988884) for Post:[Build fat static library (device + simulator) using Xcode and SDK 4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520977/build-fat-static-library-device-simulator-using-xcode-and-sdk-4)  might help you