# How to build using xcodebuild in terminal?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

What's the equivalent of building a universal static library (using xcode) vs using xcodebuild (terminal)

[image]

e.g. xcodebuild .....

Comment: You can try with the `lipo`. More information here http://www.technetexperts.com/mobile/creating-static-library-in-ios-app-development/

Comment: Thanks @QuocNguyen I have target dependencies and 2 run script (.bin/sh). Will lipo include/build them as well?

Comment: I dont try this before, but i found this, hope this help https://gist.github.com/haikusw/1383680  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520977/build-fat-static-library-device-simulator-using-xcode-and-sdk-4