# Using a static iOS library in a NativeScript 5.4 plugin

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nativescript, nativescript-plugin

NativeScript 5.4.2

tns-core-modules 5.4.3

tns-ios 5.4.2

Xcode 10.2.1

I am attempting to create a plugin for this background geolocation library for iOS: https://github.com/Yermo/background-geolocation-ios

The project produces a static library, libBackgroundGeolocation.a.

I have read the documentation on how to use a static iOS library: https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/Use-Native-iOS-Libraries#static-libraries

I have read about the required directory structure: https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/plugin-reference#directory-structure

My plugin is based on the official plugin seed, so I have a demo directory and a src directory containing my plugin code and a platforms/ios directory under that.

I have copied the BackgroundGeolocation.a file into src/platforms/ios.

I have created a src/platforms/ios/include/BackgroundGeolocation directory and copied the public header files from the project into that directory.

I notice that src/platforms/ios/include/BackgroundGeolocation/module.modulemap file has been created.

In the plugin directory I can successfully run 'npm run build'.

However, from the demo directory if I run 'tns build ios' I consistently get a "ld: Library not found for -lBackgroundGeolocation" error.

If I rename the library to libBackgroundGeolocation.a I get the "ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '.....ios/include/libBackgroundGeolocation" so I surmise it's at least recognizing that the library is there.

I thought that maybe it was a path problem so I tried setting the library include path explicitly in build.xcconfig using the full path to the platforms/ios directory.

No joy. It still doesn't find the library but if I misspell the name of the directory in the -L in build.xcconfig it flags a directory not found error.

I then thought that maybe it had to do with the targets in the library so I followed the recipe here [Build fat static library (device + simulator) using Xcode and SDK 4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520977/build-fat-static-library-device-simulator-using-xcode-and-sdk-4/5721978#5721978) to include multiple targets.

Still no joy.

I suspect I am missing something fundamental.

What am I doing wrong?

Is there a working recent working sample somewhere of how to wrap a static iOS library as a NativeScript plugin?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out adding

```
LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "$(SRCROOT)/../../node_modules/<projectname>/platforms/ios
```

to the src/platforms/ios/build.xcconfig file resolved this issue.