# Use different framework for device and simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

I am getting two builds of the same codebase delivered as two separate frameworks: one for iOS device and one for simulator

Is there a way to conditionally include one or the other depending on the target of my app?

Comment: Create a fat library by combining both the frameworks. Refer this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520977/build-fat-static-library-device-simulator-using-xcode-and-sdk-4

Comment: That’s also what googling revealed: copy everything into one folder, but use lipo for all the binaries (main and dylibs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution. Assume the frameworks for iOS device and simulator are at folders `$device` resp. `$simulator`. The merged framework will go into `$merged`:

- Copy everything from `$simulator` into `$merged`
- Copy everything from `$device` into `$merged` (for sure this will overwrite same-named binaries we copied in the step before, but we just want to make sure we have everything else (module mappings etc.); the actual merging of same-named binaries happens in the next step)
- For each binary (main and *.dylib) with name `$name` that exists both in `$simulator` and `$device`, do:
  `lipo -create $device/name $simulator/$name -output $merged/$name`

The above can easily be automated with a script.

I verified the approach with a set of frameworks we use with Flutter and it works. The easiest way is to add the `$merged` folder as a vendored framework into the podspec file

Answer (score 0):

You can write script phase to replace framework file with some conditional( maybe is target architecture).